# Terratest utility pkg for func reuse

Tags: go, terratest

Folks is there a possibility to create utils.go amongst ***_test.go** in the terratest test package to utilize a func that performs certain common validation routines across all _test.go.

I tried creating `utils/utils.go` and within the ***_test.go** imported as `"../tests/utils"`. This way able to run individual test like `go test sample_test.go -v` or `go test another_sample_test.go -v` and it yields.

But when I try `go test -v` it complains cannot reference a local package.

Am just a beginner to terratest and go lang in general. Any leads is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could try using [TestMain](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Main) to run common code beforehand that all your tests can share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go packages must in general be imported by fully-qualified paths. The fully-qualified path for a package within your project depends on what `module` path you declare in your `go.mod` file.

If you're new to Go, [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) is a good place to start.